# Parallel Game Of Life - Information exchange between threads

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, message-queue, conways-game-of-life

I am trying to implement a parallel version of 'Game Of Life'.

This parallel version divides the game's board into regions, each governed by a single thread which is responsible of calculating this region's next state and conduct the state update afterwards.

One of the constraints I am facing here is the fact that - "Each thread is allowed to access only its own region cells. All other information should be communicated from the neighboring threads by some other memory".

So, the way I understand this, even if one thread attempts to read only from a cell outside it's region, it must somehow request this state from the specific thread which is running this cell.

We are encouraged to consider the producer/consumer solution for this task, and so I have considered using a public static produce/consumer queue into which state requests shall be enqueued, but some other related issues are not clear to me:

- If thread A is conducting a job at the moment, how can I ask it to halt it's work and hand thread B it's information request and resume it's previous job afterwards? Is it even possible?
- Which thread is responsible for this queue? a unique thread which manages the queue in parallel to the regular regions threads? I am not sure.

Comment: each region thresd knows about the number of its neighbors outside of the own region. so it needs to subscribe to a receiver channel over which the missing occupancy data arrives and a sender channel, current occupancy data is transmitted over. for each cell the number of relevant messages can be stored signalling completion when all necessary info has arrived. this sketch assumes that there is a synchronizing clock thread for the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to imagine there are multiple steps in each round.
Let's say there are N threads.

1. step 1: each thread makes a list of cells it needs to discover. It puts the "question" in one of the N queues that there are (one for each thread).
2. wait for all the threads to finish
3. step 2: each thread fill the responses for its queue of question
4. wait for all the threads to finish
5. step 3: each thread computes the new state of its region
6. wait for all the threads to finish

Comment: I am not sure this answers my question, but your advice to use N queues for each thread/region sounds like a good idea to start from. I shall try to see if I can fit this into my game :) Thank you.

Comment: @AdiB The problem is that if a region has a side of N, it will have to do up to N * 4 requests. You can optimize some cases (like if an empty space has already 4 or 5 full space near, you don't need to request to the other thread, because that space won't spawn)

Comment: @AdiB This author http://www.drdobbs.com/author/Clay-Breshears has made a cycle of articles on parallelizing GoL

Comment: I am going through these articles as we type... Thanks a bunch for your help :)